# How to add items one at a time to to a new line a word document using word interop

Tags: c#, .net, ms-word, office-interop

I am trying to add these three types of content into a word doc. This is how I am trying to do it now. However, each item replaces the last one. Adding images always adds to the beginning of the page. I have a loop that calls a function to create the headers and tables, and then adds images after. I think the problem is ranges. I use a starting range of object start = 0;

How can I get these to add one at a time to to a new line in the document?

```
foreach (var category in observedColumns)
            {

                CreateHeadersAndTables();
                createPictures();
            }
```

Adding Headers:

```
                object start = 0;
                Word.Range rng = doc.Range(ref start , Missing.Value);
                Word.Paragraph heading;
                heading = doc.Content.Paragraphs.Add(Missing.Value);
                heading.Range.Text = category;
                heading.Range.InsertParagraphAfter();
```

Adding Tables:

```
            Word.Table table;
            table = doc.Content.Tables.Add(rng, 1, 5);
```

Adding Pictures:

```
            doc.Application.Selection.InlineShapes.AddPicture(@path);
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

A simple approach will be using paragraphs to handle the `Range` objects and simply insert a new paragraph one by one.

Looking at the API documentation reveals that `Paragraphs` implements an `Add` method which:

> Returns a Paragraph object that represents a new, blank paragraph
>   added to a document. (...) If Range isn't specified, the new paragraph is added after the selection or range ***or at the end of the document***.

Source: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.word.paragraphs.add(v=office.14).aspx

In that way, it gets straight forward to append new content to the document.

For completeness I have included a sample that shows how a solution might work. The sample loops through a `for` loop, and for each iteration it inserts:

- A new line of text
- A table
- A picture

The sample has is implemented as a C# console application using:

- .NET 4.5
- Microsoft Office Object Library version 15.0, and
- Microsoft Word Object Library version 15.0

... that is, the MS Word Interop API that ships with MS Office 2013.

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word;
using Application = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application;

namespace StackOverflowWordInterop
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main()
        {
            // Open word and a docx file
            var wordApplication = new Application() { Visible = true };
            var document = wordApplication.Documents.Open(@"C:\Users\myUserName\Documents\document.docx", Visible: true);

            // "10" is chosen by random - select a value that fits your purpose
            for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++)
            {
                // Insert text
                var pText = document.Paragraphs.Add();
                pText.Format.SpaceAfter = 10f;
                pText.Range.Text = String.Format("This is line #{0}", i);
                pText.Range.InsertParagraphAfter();

                // Insert table
                var pTable = document.Paragraphs.Add();
                pTable.Format.SpaceAfter = 10f;
                var table = document.Tables.Add(pTable.Range, 2, 3, WdDefaultTableBehavior.wdWord9TableBehavior);
                for (var r = 1; r <= table.Rows.Count; r++)
                    for (var c = 1; c <= table.Columns.Count; c++)
                        table.Cell(r, c).Range.Text = String.Format("This is cell {0} in table #{1}", String.Format("({0},{1})", r,c) , i);

                // Insert picture
                var pPicture = document.Paragraphs.Add();
                pPicture.Format.SpaceAfter = 10f;
                document.InlineShapes.AddPicture(Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments), "img_1.png"), Range: pPicture.Range);

            }

            // Some console ascii-UI
            Console.WriteLine("Press any key to save document and close word..");
            Console.ReadLine();

            // Save settings
            document.Save();

            // Close word
            wordApplication.Quit();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I've used your code to insert a series of text and images to a new do and works flawlessly, but when I try to do the same in an existing doc, always the new content goes to the bottom. How would I change my insertion point to top instead of end

Comment: You are not inserting new lines, you are inserting new paragraphs. How does one inserts new lines inside of the same paragraph?